# Saxon Transformerfactory placing unneceary xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" in transformer output

Tags: xslt, attributes, namespaces, saxon

I am using Sax transformer factory to do an XSLT transformation on large set of xsd files, so a particular line the xslt is as follows.

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$fileName}" 
                     doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Reference//EN" 
                     doctype-system="reference.dtd">
    <reference id="{$guid}" xml:lang="EN-US" outputclass="landscape">
        <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="$typeName"/>
        </title>
        <abstract>....
```

the reference tag being the root of the document, but the result has an unwanted xmlns:xsd attribute shown below.

```
...<reference xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       id="RANDOM-ID".....
```

this additional attribute is causing problems with parser that uses the transformed xml.
is this an issue with the XSLT or with SAXON api, how can i avoid this?

Comment: @user653335: Besides @Jörn Horstmann correct [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258660/saxon-transformerfactory-placing-unneceary-xmlnsxsd-http-www-w3-org-2001-xmls/5259051#5259051), that `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` is not an attribute but a namespace declaration, and no truly [XML Names](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) complain XML parser should have problems with those.

Answer (score 3):

By default the xsl transformation will copy namespaces that are defined in the stylesheet to the output document. You can exclude this namespace by specifying the `exclude-result-prefixes` on the `xsl:stylesheet` or the `reference` element with a value of "xsd".

Here is the relevant part of the [xslt sepcification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#literal-result-element):

> The created element node will also have a copy of the namespace nodes that were present on the element node in the stylesheet (...)
>
> A namespace URI is designated as an excluded namespace by using an exclude-result-prefixes attribute on an xsl:stylesheet element or an xsl:exclude-result-prefixes attribute on a literal result element. The value of both these attributes is a whitespace-separated list of namespace prefixes.